# Extract data from log file for last 24 hours

Tags: linux, logging, awk, sed, grep

I want to display logs for last 24 hours

I trid this but this is not best and dynamic way.

```
utmpdump /var/log/wtmp* | awk '/2022-09-22/, /2022-09-23/'
```

Any other way to display when you run script it should take last 24 hours

log file

```
[8] [528314] [    ] [        ] [pts/1       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2022-09-18T18:44:12,422480+00:00]
[8] [476233] [    ] [        ] [pts/0       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2022-09-18T19:25:11,585556+00:00]
[7] [544366] [ts/0] [centos  ] [pts/0       ] [92.46.127.82        ] [92.46.127.82   ] [2022-09-19T04:59:51,304439+00:00]
[8] [544366] [    ] [        ] [pts/0       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2022-09-19T04:59:51,517787+00:00]
[7] [544366] [ts/0] [centos  ] [pts/0       ] [92.46.127.82        ] [92.46.127.82   ] [2022-09-19T04:59:54,121598+00:00]
[8] [544366] [    ] [        ] [pts/0       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2022-09-19T04:59:54,361475+00:00]
[7] [544366] [ts/0] [centos  ] [pts/0       ] [92.46.127.82        ] [92.46.127.82   ] [2022-09-19T04:59:56,613335+00:00]
[8] [544366] [    ] [        ] [pts/0       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2022-09-19T04:59:56,810335+00:00]
[7] [544822] [ts/0] [centos  ] [pts/0       ] [92.46.127.82        ] [92.46.127.82   ] [2022-09-19T05:01:33,299161+00:00]
[8] [544822] [    ] [        ] [pts/0       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2022-09-19T05:01:33,572603+00:00]
[7] [544822] [ts/0] [centos  ] [pts/0       ] [92.46.127.82        ] [92.46.127.82   ] [2022-09-19T05:01:33,897001+00:00]
[8] [544822] [    ] [        ] [pts/0       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2022-09-19T05:01:34,152397+00:00]
[7] [544822] [ts/0] [centos  ] [pts/0       ] [92.46.127.82        ] [92.46.127.82   ] [2022-09-19T05:01:34,438247+00:00]
[8] [544822] [    ] [        ] [pts/0       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [2022-09-19T05:01:34,696364+00:00]
[7] [544822] [ts/0] [centos  ] [pts/0       ] [92.46.127.82        ] [92.46.127.82   ] [2022-09-19T05:01:34,978371+00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts, could you please do add more details on Logic part of getting expected output, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I'm specifing last 24 hours mmanually by date mentioning. Any other way to do for ex. `today's date - 24 hours`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily exactly 24 hours (but your question also only filters for yesterday and today, regardless of the current hour), but perhaps you are looking for [command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) to substitute yesterday's and today's date?

```
utmpdump /var/log/wtmp* | awk "/$(date -I -dyesterday)/,/$(date -I)/"
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. I am using GNU `date` flavor here. Also this code will print from yesterday's date to till today's date(ALL Logs, because if you simply put range `/a/,/b/` then it will catch b's 1st occurrence only but this code will print all lines of today's date.

```
awk -v yesterdayDate=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d') -v todaysDate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d) '
index($0,yesterdayDate),index($0,todaysDate){
  print
  if(index($0,todaysDate)){
    found=1
  }
}
index($0,todaysDate) && found
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU AWK has [functions for working with time](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), `mktime` does turn string compliant with format

```
YYYY MM DD HH MM SS
```

into number of seconds since epoch, `systime` does give number of seconds since epoch now. Your format might be easily reworked into `mktime`'s one, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
[stuff] [2022-09-18T18:44:12,422480+00:00]
[anotherstuff] [2022-09-18T19:25:11,585556+00:00]
[yetanotherstuff] [2022-09-19T04:59:51,304439+00:00]
```

then

```
awk '{gsub(/[-T:]/," ",$NF);s=mktime(substr($NF,2,19));print s}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1663519452
1663521911
1663556391
```

which might be easily used to select - just take element for which found value is bigger or equal to `systime()` minus 86400 (24 hours expressed in seconds)